# Parâmetro para Stored Procedure não identificado

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, parâmetros, ado.net, stored-procedures

Estou tendo um problema, que seria um erro dizendo que não existe parâmetro sendo passado para a *procedure*.

Ele está executando o seguinte código:

```
cmdProcedure.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", 0);
```

Command:

```
public List<Models.Admin> UpdateList()
{
    using (var context = new DbContext())
    {
        var cmdProcedure = new SqlCommand("GetAdmin");
        cmdProcedure.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", 0);

        using (var data = context.ExecuteSelectProcedure(cmdProcedure))
        {
            return GetList(data);
        }
    }
}

public SqlDataReader ExecuteSelectProcedure(SqlCommand cmdProcedure)
{
    cmdProcedure.Connection = _connection;
    return cmdProcedure.ExecuteReader();
}
```

Aqui esta minha procedure:

```sql
PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetAdmin]      
(
    @id int
)
AS
    BEGIN
        SET NOCOUNT ON;

        if (@id > 0)    
            SELECT * FROM Admin WHERE idAdmin = @id
        else
            SELECT * FROM Admin
    END
```

Imagem do erro:
[image: Erro]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problema corrigido! Logo após a finalização da adição de parâmetros faltava a seguinte linha:

```
cmdProcedure.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
```

problema resolvido.

Comment: Luiz, por favor, aceite sua resposta como correta para a pergunta não ficar pendente. Abraço!

Comment: Faltam 21hrs para que eu ainda possa fazer isto hehe.

Comment: Desculpe, esqueci disso =P